# Office add-in submission versions and testing

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins, office-store

I have been developing some add-ins (using office.js and vs2015) for office 365 mainly and Office 2016 and been resubmitting an outlook add-in and the versions for excel and word, but always get fail on approval as there is a version here and there of office 2013 or a browser that do not load or run. (Now I can't test it with office 2013 simply because there isn't one to download from the official website and I am developing in commercial use, so I cannot really use a pirate copy for that - how would I be able to test it - any suggestions will most likely work)

Does anyone have a good documentation as to what api runs with what version or an example of manifest and api versions working only for 2016 and 365. The one on microsoft's website with all versions of api do not really make sense.

And also given that upon uploading the manifest file for submission - it says it only works with office 365 and/or 2016 - why does Microsoft actually test it with 2013?

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the latest information on Office Add-in host and platform availability [here](https://dev.office.com/add-in-availability).

If you have a valid Office365 subscription and do not have access to Office 2013 you can download it using the following CDN link:
[Business](https://c2rsetup.officeapps.live.com/c2r/download.aspx?productReleaseID=O365BusinessRetail&platform=X86&language=en-us&version=O15GA&source=O15OLSO365)

If your add-in does not support Office 2013 due to the use of APIs unsupported in Office 2013, these APIs should be clearly referenced in the manifest. Once unsupported APIs are present the add-in is not required to support Office 2013.